# WSO2 API dynamic client registration endpoint

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I've been looking through the doc of wso2 apim. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/apidocs/publisher/index.html#guide

The APIM publisher(https://publisher.apim.test.com:9443) through IS single sign on to login.
[image]

In my case, I use the postman to send the request:

Header
[image]
Request Body
[image]
But I got 403 error response. 
[image]
The APIM publisher log.

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2018-02-27 17:11:23,103]  WARN {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} -  potential cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:<anonymous>, ip:172.xx.x.xxx, method:POST, uri:/client-registration/v0.11/register, error:required token is missing from the request) {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger}
```

As expected I should get the correct response payload like:

```
{
    "callBackURL": "www.google.lk",
    "jsonString":
    "{
    \"username\":\"Amanda\",
    \"redirect_uris\":\"www.google.lk\",
    \"tokenScope\":[Ljava.lang.String;@3a73796a,
    \"client_name\":\"Amanda_rest_api_publisher\",
    \"grant_types\":\"authorization_code password refresh_token iwa:ntlm
    urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:saml2-bearer client_credentialsimplicit\"
    }",
    "clientName": null,
    "clientId": "HfEl1jJPdg5tbtrxhAwybN05QGoa",
    "clientSecret": "l6c0aoLcWR3fwezHhc7XoGOht5Aa"
}
```

Will be appreciated if anyone can help. Thanks.

Comment: And - what is written in the logs?

Comment: I have added APIM publisher carbon log above.Thank you.

Comment: NOTICE: Obfuscate your image (we can decode your password)

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your java version?.

Some updates of JDK 1.8 (for example, JDK1.8.0_151) are affected by a [known issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789) related to GZIP decoding, which may prevent these CSRF-related configurations from working for the product.

Be sure that you are running on JDK1.8.0_144 or JDK1.8.0_077. We have verified that these JDK versions are not affected by the [known issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789).